# What, formally speaking, is a react component?

Tags: reactjs

Consider

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    //...
  }
});
```

as well as

```
var element = React.createElement(MyComponent);
```

Which specifically, or where specifically, is the "component"? Is it the object returned by the call to `React.createClass(..)`? Is it the object returned by `React.createElement(..)`? Is it behind the scenes somewhere in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post answers the question in great detail](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/react-components-elements-and-instances-90800811f8ca#.2zifs55jk).

In short: components are -- literally speaking -- functions that take an object with a `props` field and, in turn, return a `React.Element`. Components can be pure functions, or JS classes (which are functions with syntactic sugar over them anyway). You can define a component via `React.createClass`; the output of `React.createClass` is -- as I understand it -- still literally a component (although several instances of it can be instantiated behind the scenes via React, each of which can be accesssed via `this` within the class definition; these instances are also components).

Finally, `React.Element` is nothing but a "description" of a component instance or a dom node. Literally, it is a javascript object with fields like `props` and `children` (it also has a field `type`, which is described in the article). **Crucially, an instance of a `React.Element` is NOT a component; it merely describes one. Moreover, the output of a `React.createClass()` is a component, as well as any function that takes an object with a `prop` field and returns an instance of a `React.Element`.**

Answer (score 1):

There's a post on the React blog that answers your question.

http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Basically, components are your class definitions, elements are created from your components in `render()`, and instances are your component's representation in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously http://facebook.github.io/react/ is the authority here - a component is conceptual construct that has properties, state, and a render function. Although the first two are optional. Components are typed using a "class" (ES5 prototypes, ES6 classes, etc), which React is formally made aware of using the `createClass` function. Component instances are elements in a larger whole, loaded into a UI context (the browser, a phone, whatever), usually called an app, and created with `createElement`.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that `createClass()` returns a component class, and `createElement` returns a component instance?

Comment: that would not be inappropriate use of terminology